# Calculating distance between two post codes

Tags: php, mysql, geocoding, distance

I would like some help with how to go about calculating the distance between two post codes. Here is the setup that I wish to have, let me give you a scenario.

A user logs into my website (they have provided their details, their postcode being one of them). That data is stored in the `users` table.

I have another table with details about `locations`. I would like to display locations (and the distance) that are closest to the user.

I know that there are certain methods that can be used, for example:

Converting a postcode to a long-lat and using built in methods to calculate the distance, I think Google offer a free service. But I have no idea how I would implement such a thing. All the tutorials I have taken a look at seem too complicated and for the time being I want a very crude and simple solution upon which I can build and more importantly learn!

I am fairly familiar with PHP and MySQL when it comes to basic input/output of data. But I am not sure of the best way to handle the information with regards to user data, and the locations of the 'businesses'.

Any suggestions, comments will be more than appreciated.

Comment: Your question is rather broad. What have you tried?

Comment: [Calculate the Distance Between Two Coordinates (latitude, longitude)](http://snipplr.com/view/2531/)

Comment: I know it is, I haven't really tried anything, I know how to store and retrieve items from a database, but I have never used the data with respect to the geocoding that I have looked at with regards to the service Google offer.

Comment: You can obtain lat long info using google or foursquare's apis typically by address, but even just venue name might be enough for foursquare. From that you store the latlong for each location and then factor in sammitch's suggestion.

Comment: I have checked here but I am not sure how to implement the code to just return the LAT/LONG. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests

Answer (score 1):

If you're US based, this API should meet your needs: https://www.zipcodeapi.com

It's made specifically to find distance between two zip codes, tells you the long-lat for zip codes, find all zips relative to a location, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get postcode northings eastings data free from ordinance survey (credit them on your webpage to get free)

2 calculate distance from the appropriate csv flat file (M.csv contains all manchester postcodes and north and eastness).

3. Distance is sqrt((n1-n2)**2 +(e1-e2)**2) - excuse my fortran
4. If its slow,and you want an approximate distance create a small database of first half postcodes averages so you are looking up M20 not M20 3nb.

5 NB google don't like you using their postcode apis outside google Maps.

6. I am wondering about an algorithm so that for short distances, if you are looking at places close to a postcode, you just search M postcodes for a M postcode (and maybe nearby post areas like SK, OL, if you have a table of adjacent postcode areas).

7 Any body taken this further?